# My oledb connection works on a workbook but not on the other

Tags: vba, excel, database-connection, adodb

So i have this code in two different workbooks, two different files. They are even in the same folder in the same computer.

```
strFile = "Z:\service\climatizacion.mdb"

strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & strFile

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Open strCon

strSQL = "SELECT codigorep, cantidad, precio, descripcion FROM cotizacion WHERE codigorep = " & lngInput & ";"
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.RECORDSET")
rs.Open Source:=strSQL, ActiveConnection:=cn, CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, LockType:=adLockOptimistic
```

In one of the workbooks it works perfect, it selects all the data i need from the database.

On the other it gives me the Runtime error 3001 (The application is using arguments that are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another) when I try to open the recordset.

I figured through this code that the connection was the problem (I may be wrong)

```
If cn.State = adStateOpen Then
  MsgBox "connected"
Else
  MsgBox "not connected"
End If
```

I cannot find the difference between these workbooks that can make this connection or the entire code work or make it stop working.
All the variables are declared, the tables exist, i can open them through access with no problems, the database is located on a pc on my local network.

The database is an mdb file, from access 97. And i'm running this on excel 2003, both workbooks, and both were created by me with the same excel 2003.

Thank you in advance for taking the time to read this :D

Comment: Do both workbook have a reference set to the ADO library?  You're using late binding for the connection and recordset objects, but you're still using constants defined in the ADO reference (`adOpenDynamic`, `adLockOptimistic`,`adStateOpen`)